# Configure / Add a FQDN to /etc/hosts?

Tags: server, bash

I'm trying to set up iRedmail 0.8.5 and I keep getting this error.

```
root@danielbts11:~# cd /home/iRedMail-0.8.5

root@danielbts11:/home/iRedMail-0.8.5# bash iRedMail.sh

hostname: Name or service not known

hostname: Name or service not known

< ERROR > Please configure a fully qualified domain name (FQDN) in /etc/hosts before we go further.

Example:

127.0.0.1   mail.iredmail.org mail localhost
```

---

I have no clue on what to put in that file it's asking me to edit.  My domain is dbatease.com and my ip is 74.91.123.215 running Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 1):

You edit the `/etc/hosts` file to contain fully qualified hostname:

```
74.91.123.215 mail.dbatease.com mail
```

That should made the trick

Comment: didn't work, but I figured it out, hostname@dbatease.com hostname

Comment: Your mail server setup is somehow incorrect, in fqdn you are not pointing usernames, that is dns record, not email address. `hostname --fqdn` should match to that also.

Comment: I just noticed that I made and error while typing what worked for me.  DO NOT USE AT @!  I did hostname.dbatease.com hostname .  I'm sorry for any confusion.

Comment: For systems without permanent IP one should add `127.0.1.1 hostname` instead. This is actually a work around this bug:  https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=316099